# How can I undo an accidental newline in bash?

Tags: bash, line-editor

If I unintentionally add a newline in a command, as far as I can tell, the only way to undo it is to press Ctrl+c and type the command again. For example:

```
$ cat 'John's File'
> ^C
$ cat "John's File"
```

This is annoying if the original command is long.

Is there a way to delete the newline and remove the `>` prompt so that I can go back to the original command?

Comment: Press KeyUp? This works for me with bash3. No newline even if it was in my X11 clipboard. What effects do you run into?

Comment: I don't really want my history littered with partial commands.

Comment: Ah, got that you want to get rid of `>` and return back without pressing Ctrl-C, sorry misunderstood. I don't really know, it enters new mode in which it waits from you to complete typed command because it's incomplete. I usually do KeyUp after Ctrl-C/D if there is a mistake and fix it. The whole command appears intact after I press KeyUp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to delete the newline ... ?

Actually: No.
But there are excellent workarounds.

As you have already introduced an <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the line has been stored in the list of commands executed. Press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to get out of the command, then, without re-typing, press <kbd>up-arrow</kbd>. The command entered appears again, and could be edited.

Answer (score 2):

From `man bash`

```
       edit-and-execute-command (C-xC-e)
          Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell commands.  Bash attempts to invoke $VISUAL, $EDITOR, and emacs as the editor, in that order.
```

Comment: This doesn't work. After editing and saving the temp file, the command is executed properly, but I'm left back at the `>` prompt.